# Selection and Deselection of Radio Buttons is not working properly in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, radio-button

***CODE***

```
holder.radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                holder.radioButton.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                holder.radioButton.setChecked(true);
            }

        }
    });
```

***PROBLEM***

When I'm using this code my Radio-Button gets deselected immediately after getting selected and the inverse if I change the conditions. How to hold the state of Radio-Button??

Comment: You are checking the radiobutton in onCheckChanged , which is causing the issue, 
onCheckChanged is called only when there is change is a state of radio button , you  don't need to mark it as true/false inside this

Comment: Can we use onClickListener in place of onCheckedChangeListener??

Comment: If you want to check is radio button is  true/false , you can save value of isChecked of onCheckChanged in a global variable

Comment: onClickListener will also cause the same issue.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want to show if the image is selected or not.

Comment: If someone check on radio button , you want to show image/ hide according , or you need to always show selected radio button with image

Comment: With the global variable if I have to change the state of the Radio-Button  I have to put that statement outside the 'onCheckChanged' method??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237177/discussion-between-arsh-and-nitish-chaudhary).